# Spring boot 2.0.4 application properties not being overridden by command line json

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I am using spring boot 2.0.4 and creating an executable jar.

I have below properties defined in my application.properties

```
configserviceendpoint=devendpoint
```

I am following [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) to pass the properties as .json and tried running the application using below commands

> 1. java -Dspring.application.json='{"configserviceendpoint":"prod end point"}' -jar myapp.jar
> 2. java -jar myapp.jar --spring.application.json='{"configserviceendpoint":"prod end point"}'

While trying to access the property in my code it still shows the value defined in `application.properties` and not the one which is being passed in command as .json

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to run it as following:

`java -jar myapp.jar --configserviceendpoint="prod/endpoint"`

Comment: Thanks dominikbrandon, it had worked for me as well, but i have many other custom properties which i want to pass as json rather than command line

Comment: I created a simple demo application and you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/dominikbrandon/2d6f72ddc9fe3ba1ac082ab9c4a9badf). I have tested it and when you run it without any parameters, it uses property from `application.properties` file, but you can run it with `--spring.application.json='{"property.source":"command-line"}'` and you'll see that the passed parameter will override the default one.

Comment: Thanks dominikbrandon, Works well but with executable jar it does not work, Created a sample project with my use case. Please refer [link](https://github.com/vibrations1/springbootcommandline/tree/master/commandlineJson)

Comment: Please check out [these logs](https://gist.github.com/dominikbrandon/94c1b3bbe74831f2860d75a59a75846c). I have cloned and run your application and was able to overwrite the default property value.

Comment: Thanks a lot dominikbrandon for putting sincere efforts and trying this out. Helped to figure out the issue now, Seems its not working with windows command prompt (not sure if i am doing something wrong) while works perfectly with gitbash . Please refer [logs](https://gist.github.com/vibrations1/15dbcdc7e3405612deaedf3f15963826) .Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad I could help!